# How do I initialize a property that depends on another property, when I don't have access to self yet?

Tags: swift

I have two properties in my class. See this terrible example:

```
var length
var doubleLength
```

How do I initialize `doubleLength` based on `length`?

```
init() {
    self.length = ...
    self.doubleLength = self.length * 2

    super.init()
}
```

I get an error that I can't access `self` before I call `super.init()`. Well I need to set all my variables before I can even call `super.init()` so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: What does your `super.init()` look like that it requires your properties be set before it's accessed? If those properties are members of the superclass, you should have a designated initializer in your superclass that accepts `length` and `doubleLength`, and call that instead.

Comment: They're not members of the superclass.

Comment: Then how is the superclass accessing those properties? Why do they need to be set before you call `super.init()`?

Comment: @CraigOtis Because that's how Swift works? You need to initialize all the instance variables in your class before you call super.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time coming up with a real-world case in which this occurs. If it's a computed property, than your property based on it (like `doubleLength`) should also be computed. You don't need to assign it. If you *do* need to assign it before calling super, you should pass it in as a constructor arg, or assign it to some initial/default value. Can you help me understand a good scenario/example?

Comment: Can we see a (minimal) full example, please? It's hard to figure out what's going on, otherwise.

Comment: @MattGibson https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a38fbbd41f8b91fb2567

Comment: Ah, right—so if you just make length a variable rather than a property (i.e. `var length: Int = 50`) then it works fine? Certainly the error goes away for me. I'm guessing this is because code in a property getter or setter might require the base class to be fully initialised to work properly; this restriction is discussed in one of the WWDC videos, but sadly I can't remember which one, exactly. Might've been _Advanced Swift_. With a simple initialised declaration of the variable, I guess the compiler can see you're not using the base.

Answer (score 4):

if `self.doubleLength` is always supposed to be twice `self.length` (in this example) have you considered just using a computed property?

```
class MyClass: MySuperClass {
    var length: Double
    var doubleLength: Double {
        return self.length * 2
    }
    init(len: Double) {
        self.length = len
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought computed properties were more so for when it might change from call to call. This should be the same from the get go, right?

Comment: I would say if `doubleLength` depends on `length` the cleanest code is using a computed property. If computing it is expensive you may need to cache the result for performance reasons, but if it's not: I say clean code trumps insignificant performance gains

Comment: Computed properties are for exactly this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily delay the initialization of `doubleLength` an implicitly unwrapped optional, which will allow to temporarily assign a value to `nil` and assign it at a later time.

```
class Something: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var doubleLength: Int! = nil
    var length: Int {
        return 50
    }
    init() {
        super.init()
        doubleLength = length * 2
    }
}
```

Anyway, in this specific case I think it would be nicer to make `doubleLength` a computed property, since it can be always be computed from the value of `length`. Your class will be like

```
class Something: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var doubleLength: Int {
        return length * 2
    }
    var length: Int {
        return 50
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue is keeping `doubleLength` in sync with `length`, though I might be mistaken

Comment: @JackWu given the question, the problem seems to be with the initialization. I cannot reproduce it, though.

Comment: `self.length` is a computed property, does that change things?

Comment: @DougSmith it does, I can finally reproduce the issue. Can you post the actual code you're using?

Comment: Ok, and why do you need to have set before calling super.init?

Comment: A compile error. You need to initialize all instance variables before calling super.

Comment: Ok, then you can use the unwrapped optional trick. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your full reproduction, which is:

```
import UIKit

class Something: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var doubleLength: Int

    var length: Int {
        return 50
    }

    init() {
        doubleLength = length * 2
        super.init()
    }
}
```

From this we can see that you're using a getter to return your property. I think this is what's causing the problem. For example, if you just do this:

```
import UIKit

class Something: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var doubleLength: Int

    // Simple variable, no code.
    var length = 50

    init() {
        doubleLength = length * 2
        super.init()
    }
}
```

...then that works fine.

I believe this is because the Swift compiler is trying to prevent you from doing anything that might mean you use the base class's methods, properties or variables before it's been initialised. I know you're technically *not*, in your example, but consider how hard it is to trace back and see what's being done from your initialiser. For example, if you were to do:

```
var length: Int {
    // Where "width" is a made-up property of UICollectionViewLayout
    return width * 3
}
```

...then your code would be run from your initialiser and use a property of UICollectionViewLayout before its own `init` had been called, therefore making it possibly invalid.

So my best guess is that this is the Swift compiler making a blanket ban on calling out to *any* code outside the subclass initialiser before the super is initialised.

You get exactly the same error if you do this, for example:

```
class Something: UICollectionViewLayout {    
    func foo() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    init() {
        foo() // error: 'self' used before super.init call
        super.init()
    }
}
```

The place I remember this being explained is the "Intermediate Swift" video from WWDC 2014, from slide 191, about 20 minutes in, but I'm guessing it's somewhere in the book, too...

Answer (score -6):

A property that depends on another is bad practice. Just like when you design a database, you avoid calculated fields, when you design classes, you also avoid calculated fields. Instead of having a doubleLength property, you should instead have a getDoubleLength method that returns the length * 2.

Comment: why do you say this is bad practice?

Comment: It's how I was taught.

Comment: basically, the length is something that describes the object, so it is a property. Double the length is an action upon the length, not a description of the object, so it is not a property.

Comment: But, to take Apple's example early in the swift tutorials, area is certainly a computed property of a rectangle.  They apparently consider the concept of computed properties to be important enough that making the blank statement "a property that depends on another is bad practice" seems unwise.

Comment: Swift has computed properties and `didSet`/`willSet` for just this purpose.